# Dialog Activity has a layout on the background

Tags: java, android, dialog

I am trying to make a dialog activity when the notification is clicked but I encountered some trouble.

[image]

as you can see, the dialog is opened after clicking the notification but the black background is not necessary, how could I remove this ? I wanted to do is just pop.out the dialog box on the application before resuming to the the background activity.
Thanks.

Here is my code for the manifest.

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity> <!-- android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity" -->
        <activity
            android:name=".DialogMEssage"
            android:excludeFromRecents="true"
            android:launchMode="singleInstance"
            android:taskAffinity=""
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Dialog.Alert" >
        </activity>
    </application>
```

The layout file is totally empty and the code for the dialog is as follows.

```
public class DialogMEssage extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_dialog_m_essage);
        
        AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
        alertDialog.setTitle("Alert");
        alertDialog.setMessage("Alert message to be shown");
        alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEUTRAL, "OK",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });
        alertDialog.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: The point of using a `Dialog` theme on an `Activity` is to have the `Activity` itself act as a `Dialog`, not to show another separate `AlertDialog`.

Comment: can you make dialog in onMessageReceived() in your push notification service? it's look better

Comment: in other way you can create dialog class and call it every where u want

Comment: Sir @MikeM. , when I remove the dialog theme on the activity, it will open other activity. 
I wanted is to remain on the background activity.

Comment: No, that's not what I was suggesting. I mean, get rid of the `AlertDialog`, and set up the `Activity` like a `Dialog`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove this line from your code

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_dialog_m_essage);
```

It will not set that background layout

Add `DialogMEssage.this.finish();` in onClick like this

```
AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
        alertDialog.setTitle("Alert");
        alertDialog.setMessage("Alert message to be shown");
        alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEUTRAL, "OK",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                        DialogMEssage.this.finish();
                    }
                });
        alertDialog.show();
```

Comment: it removes the background layout but the title remains after ignoring the alert dialog.

this is the screen shot.
https://ibb.co/cL86GB3

Answer (score 2):

You can try the following approach.

1 - Add the following style:

```
<style name="Theme.AppCompat.Dialog.Alert.Custom" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Dialog.Alert">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

2 - Go to the manifest and update the theme of your activity:

```
<activity
    android:name=".DialogMEssage"
    android:excludeFromRecents="true"
    android:launchMode="singleInstance"
    android:taskAffinity=""
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Dialog.Alert.Custom" >
</activity>
```

3 - (Optional) You can close the activity once the user dismisses the dialog:

```
alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEUTRAL, "OK",
new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        dialog.dismiss();
        // Close the activity
        finish();
    }
});
```